# Does the Airflow scheduler rerun previous DAG Runs when introducing new tasks to the DAG?

Tags: dynamic, task, airflow

I have a DAG definition that dynamically adds tasks from a config to the DAG, for example:

```
for k, v in config.iteritems():
    bash_task = BashOperator(task_id='{}_task'.format(k), ...)
    ...
```

If I added more items to `config`, will the Airflow scheduler rerun all previous jobs, or will I have to do that manually (by running `airflow scheduler` or `airflow backfill`)?

Answer (score 1):

The scheduler will not inspect all TaskInstances of all previous DagRuns.  If you run `airflow backfill` for the relevant date range it should pick up all incomplete tasks.

A word of warning: Airflow is not set up for **removing** tasks from a DAG.  Your DB would likely retain references to no longer valid task IDs and Airflow might refuse to do anything with that DAG until the tasks are restored or all other TaskInstances in the DAG are erased.